# Insert multiple file names in database column

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this file uploading code which is working fine. The only issue I have is when i upload multiple files, it creates multiple rows in database for each file. For instance, if I upload 5 files, it will create 5 new rows with same message but with different file name. It's not binding all files in one message and not creating a single row for message with multiple files in database.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])){
    $files = $_FILES['files'];

     $uploaded = array();
     $failed = array();
     $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg','gif','png','txt', 'doc','docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'zip','rar','gz','7zip','ppt', 'pptx','rtf','pdf','svg','sav','csv');

     foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

        $file_temp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];
        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
            if($file_error === 0){
                if($file_size <= 20000000){
                   $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                   $file_destination = '../files/wcfiles/'.$file_name_new;
                   $file_destination = '../files/wcfiles/'.strtolower($file_name);

                   $file_db_path_array = array();
                   array_push($file_db_path_array, strtolower($file_name)); 

                   $file_db_path = 'msg_files/'. $file_db_path_array;

                   if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_destination)){
                    $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                    } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload";}
                    } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";}
                    } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] errored with code {$file_error}";}
                    } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";}
                        }

$ins_message = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO conversation (msg_date, msg_id, msg_from, msg_to, msg_message, msg_files) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$ins_message->bind_param("ssssss", $msg_date, $msg_id, $msg_from, $msg_to, $msg_message, $file_db_path);

$ins_message->execute();
$ins_message->close();
```

File code

```
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach (explode(',', $msg_rows['msg_files']) as $file ) {
 echo '<li><a href="../files/wcfiles/"'.$file.'>'.$file.'</a></li>';}
 echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to push the file path values into an array in your `foreach` loop. Then, after the loop, `join` each file path array element into a string with a comma in between each, to get your complete file paths string to insert into the database.

**First** instantiate an array, to hold the file path values, before the `foreach` loop.

```
$file_db_path_array = [];
foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
  // ...
```

**Next** move your database insertion code to after your `foreach` loop closes:

```
} // end of foreach $files['name']
$ins_message = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO conversation (msg_date, msg_id, msg_from, msg_to, msg_message, msg_files) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$ins_message->bind_param("ssssss", $msg_date, $msg_order_id, $msg_from, $msg_to, $msg_message, $file_db_path);

$ins_message->execute();
$ins_message->close();
```

**Then** replace the `$file_db_path` assignment line with:

```
array_push($file_db_path_array, 'msg_files/'.strtolower($file_name_new));
```

**Finally**, in the database insertion code, change `$file_db_path` to `join(',', $file_db_path_array)`.

```
$ins_message->bind_param("ssssss", $msg_date, $msg_order_id, $msg_from, $msg_to, $msg_message, join(',', $file_db_path_array));
```

---

And here's the complete `foreach` loop and database insertion:

```
$file_db_path_array = [];
foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

    $file_temp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
    $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
    $file_error = $files['error'][$position];
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error === 0){
            if($file_size <= 20000000){
                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = '../files/wcfiles/'.$file_name_new;

                array_push($file_db_path_array, 'msg_files/'.strtolower($file_name_new)); 

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_destination)){
                    $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload";
                }
            } else {
                $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";
            }
        } else {
            $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] errored with code {$file_error}";
        }
    } else {
        $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";
    }
}
$file_db_path = join(',', $file_db_path_array);
$ins_message = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO conversation (msg_date, msg_id, msg_from, msg_to, msg_message, msg_files) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$ins_message->bind_param("ssssss", $msg_date, $msg_order_id, $msg_from, $msg_to, $msg_message, $file_db_path);

$ins_message->execute();
$ins_message->close();
```

---

Later, when you want to display the list of files with each message, for each message, `explode` the file list, using comma, to get an array, then loop over the array to display each file.

```
// this is inside your messages display loop,
// assuming the files field is assigned to variable $files_string

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( explode(',', $files_string) as $file ) {
  echo '<li><a href="../files/wcfiles/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks bloody bro, I am testing it. Thanks alot for your detailed answer.

Comment: Please check code and assist me if I have done anything wrong. I am also now getting undefined variable on $file_db_path.

Comment: @stackkid My fault. I forgot to add `$file_db_path_string = ''` before the `foreach` loop, to instantiate the file path string you build up when looping. I think the array approach is more elegant so I've updated my answer to feature that approach.

Comment: @stackkid I see you changed your question code, and you're trying to include both approaches. They are exclusive, one or the other, not both. Please check my answer again. I've tested the bare bones and I'm not getting errors.

Comment: When I try to `$file_db_path_array = array(); array_push($file_db_path_array, strtolower($file_name)); print_r($file_db_path_array);` , i got the following `Array ( [0] => new.jpg ) Array ( [0] => new.jpg [1] => old.jpg )` and error `( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\cl\conversation.php` on line 98 ... it seems its looping for files too and not attaching all files at once. also, no insertion in db –

Comment: Have you tried the code example I provided? Replace your `foreach` loop and database insertion code with the complete example I provided.

Comment: Sorry, it was sent mistakenly... Thanks, yes, I did... its giving me attachments as `keyword sheet.xlsx,new.jpg,old.jpg` .... Also, giving error in bind_param line where you have used `join(',', $file_db_path_array)`

( ! ) Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\cl\conversation.php on line 93

Comment: @stackkid I updated the complete example to provide the variable required by strict standards.

Comment: @stackkid Please explain what problem are you having with the attachments: `keyword sheet.xlsx,new.jpg,old.jpg`.

Comment: The only problem I have now is, I want them separated because they will be downloaded. Also, I have a complete email system at back which checks the name of file in the database, and then attach it when we send it.

Comment: When do you want them separated? After you retrieve them from the database? In your question you state: "The only issue I have is when i upload multiple files, it creates multiple rows in database for each file." That tells me you want all the files in one row of the database. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted them to be included in one row with message. but for users, Its like an unordered list of files with message. so one can download them separately and i can call them with my email code too.

Comment: @stackkid I added a bit of code to show how to convert the files list string into an array, which you can then loop over to create an unordered list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done that and it has separated the files as I want, now the only issue remain, unfortunately, is that it's not taking the file name..It shows me the names of files attached but in anchor, it's showing just the path and not appending the file name to it. updating the code.

Comment: You closed the `href` value quote before the file name, so the file name is not included in the link, and the file name becomes an (ingnored) attribute. I updated my answer with the fix. Take a look at the unordered file list loop I wrote.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bloodyKnuckles, I know no words can express my gratitude to you. I am finally able to achieve what i have been trying since last week, and that is all possible just because of your benevolence... thank you once again...

Comment: Hello again, and sorry to disturb you. I just find out that when I upload the duplicate file, it replaces the old one. though the uniqid code is there, its not working. It did before and changed the file name to a long string of numerics. Is it possible to change the code to keep the name as it was but add 1, 2, 3 after that?